# IOS - UICollectionView - Pass data to child view via segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm struggling with passing data to a child view via a `UICollectionView` - basically I want to populate several `UITextField` in the child view with the relevant data based on item clicked - this is a screenshot of my view -

[image]

Here is a snipped of the array data to show how its put together -

```
 sightsObject *sight13 = [[sightsObject alloc] initWithsiteTitle:@"ssd"   siteSection:@"views" siteType:@"" siteSubTitle:@"" siteDescription:@"" siteMapUrl:@"docks" sitePic:@"further"];
```

the array is currently static - so its compiled as follows -

```
 self.sightsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sight1, sight2, sight3, sight4, sight5, sight6, sight7, sight8,sight9,sight10, sight11, sight12,sight13, nil];

 self.sectionData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"beatles", @"docks",@"unique",@"museums", @"Football",@"Tours",@"Views",@"Further Afield", nil];
```

The uiCollectionView is populated as follows -

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

_selectedItemIndex = indexPath.row;


CSCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath]
NSString *s = self.sectionData[indexPath.section];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"siteSection like %@", s];
NSArray *filteredArr = [self.sightsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
NSLog(@"Value of hello = %@", filteredArr);
sightsObject *rightS = filteredArr[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text =rightS.siteTitle;
cell.textBrief.text = rightS.siteSubTitle;
cell.imageIco.image = [UIImage imageNamed:rightS.sitePic];

return cell;
```

}

I have stored the selected index path in this method -

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


   self.selectedItemIndex = indexPath.row; //stored as NSInteger

}
```

finally i try and pass the data as follows -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


    NSArray* selectedItem = [_sightsArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedItemIndex ];

    SightViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
    destController.viewTit = selectedItem.siteTitle ;




}
```

but I get an error stating property siteTitle not found on NSArray..

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Do you want to pass the selected index to destination controller?

Comment: I want to pass strings from the array at the indexpath.row - siteTitle is the title of the artice, I'd also want to pass SiteImage, siteDesc etc

Comment: Could you please confirm the data type you expect for `selectedItem`? From your code (`prepareForSegue` method) it appears that you obtain an `NSArray* selectedItem` from an `NSArray _sightsArray`? I'd suggest that in your `prepareForSegue` method, you need to recover a `sightsObject` (not an `NSArray`) with an `NSString` property `siteTitle`, that you can then pass to the `destController` property `viewTit`.

Comment: Hi andrew - my data is extracted from sightsarray - which contains multiple sightsObjects - such as sight13 - if for example I clicked on the cell relating to sight13 - i'd like to extract the relevant siteTitle property and pass that on to the destination view controller - if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same using

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FirstView"]) {
        NSString* selectedItem = [_sightsArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedItemIndex];
        SightViewController *destController = (SightViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destController.selString = selectedItem;
    }
}
```

In desController.h file declare the string variable as

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *selString;
```

Comment: ok - i guess the above would give me the array related top the index- say it equated to array13 above - how would I then extract the siteTitle property of this array?

Comment: Is the array _sightsArray an String array? if not then its returning sightsObject as indicated by vacawama? If so then use sightsObject *selectedItem = [_sightsArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedItemIndex]; destController.selString = selectedItem.siteTitle;

Comment: perfect - thats waht i'm after - thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your `_sightArray` contains objects of type `sightsObject`.  Try:

```
sightsObject *selectedItem = [_sightsArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedItemIndex ];
```